# Getting values from modal to main view in VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I make my first project in Vue.

I have small problem.
I need to get a value from Datatable (marked in code: console.log (self.selectedContent); // here is my result @@) - to my main view and display it. How can I do this?

My Main.vue:

```
<template>
  <CCard>
    <CCardHeader>
      <CIcon name="cil-input-power"/>
      Dodaj zlecenie
    </CCardHeader>
    <CCardBody>
      <CRow>
        <CCol sm="12">
          <CForm>
            <div class="tab-content py-3" id="myTabContent">
              <div class="tab-pane fade" :class="{ 'active show': isActive('tab1') }" id="tab1">
                <h4 class="py-3 d-inline-block pe-5 me-5">Dane przewoźnika </h4>

                <CButton
                  @click="warningModal = true"
                  color="primary"
                >
                  Uzupełnij
                </CButton>
                <CInput
                  v-model.trim="$v.form.carrier_id.$model"
                  :isValid="checkIfValid('carrier_id')"
                  type="hidden"
                />
                <CRow>
                  <CCol md="6">
                    <CInput
                      maxlength="255"
                      label="Nazwa przewoźnika*"
                      v-model.trim="$v.form.carrier_name.$model"
                      :isValid="checkIfValid('carrier_name')"
                      placeholder="Wpisz nazwę przewoźnika"
                      invalidFeedback="To pole jest wymagane i musi zawierać minimum 3 znaki i maksimum 255 znaków"
                    />
                  </CCol>
                  <CCol md="6">
                    <CInput
                      maxlength="255"
                      label="NIP przewoźnika*"
                      v-model.trim="$v.form.carrier_nip.$model"
                      :isValid="checkIfValid('carrier_nip')"
                      placeholder="Wpisz NIP przewoźnika"
                      invalidFeedback="To pole jest wymagane i musi zawierać minimum 3 znaki i maksimum 255 znaków"
                    />
                  </CCol>
                </CRow>
                <CRow>
                  <CCol md="6">
                    <CInput
                      maxlength="255"
                      label="Regon przewoźnika*"
                      v-model.trim="$v.form.carrier_regon.$model"
                      :isValid="checkIfValid('carrier_regon')"
                      placeholder="Wpisz regon przewoźnika"
                      invalidFeedback="To pole jest wymagane i musi zawierać minimum 3 znaki i maksimum 255 znaków"
                    />
                  </CCol>
                  <CCol md="6">
                    <CInput
                      maxlength="255"
                      label="Email przewoźnika*"
                      v-model.trim="$v.form.carrier_email.$model"
                      :isValid="checkIfValid('carrier_email')"
                      placeholder="Wpisz email przewoźnika"
                      invalidFeedback="To pole jest wymagane i musi zawierać minimum 3 znaki i maksimum 255 znaków"
                    />
                  </CCol>
                </CRow>
                <CRow>
                  <CCol md="6">
                    <CInput
                      maxlength="255"
                      label="Telefon przewoźnika*"
                      v-model.trim="$v.form.carrier_phone.$model"
                      :isValid="checkIfValid('carrier_phone')"
                      placeholder="Wpisz telefon przewoźnika"
                      invalidFeedback="To pole jest wymagane i musi zawierać minimum 3 znaki i maksimum 255 znaków"
                    />
                  </CCol>
                  <CCol md="6">
                    <CInput
                      maxlength="255"
                      label="Kod pocztowy przewodnika*"
                      v-model.trim="$v.form.carrier_postal_code.$model"
                      :isValid="checkIfValid('carrier_postal_code')"
                      placeholder="Wpisz kod pocztowy przewodnika"
                      invalidFeedback="To pole jest wymagane i musi zawierać minimum 3 znaki i maksimum 255 znaków"
                    />
                  </CCol>
                </CRow>
                <CRow>
                  <CCol md="6">
                    <CInput
                      maxlength="255"
                      label="Adres przewoźnika*"
                      v-model.trim="$v.form.carrier_street.$model"
                      :isValid="checkIfValid('carrier_street')"
                      placeholder="Wpisz adres przewoźnika"
                      invalidFeedback="To pole jest wymagane i musi zawierać minimum 3 znaki i maksimum 255 znaków"
                    />
                  </CCol>
                  <CCol md="6">
                    <CInput
                      maxlength="255"
                      label="Miasto przewodnika*"
                      v-model.trim="$v.form.carrier_city.$model"
                      :isValid="checkIfValid('carrier_city')"
                      placeholder="Wpisz miasto przewodnika"
                      invalidFeedback="To pole jest wymagane i musi zawierać minimum 3 znaki i maksimum 255 znaków"
                    />
                  </CCol>
                </CRow>
                <CRow>
                  <CCol md="12">
                    <CInput
                      maxlength="255"
                      label="Email do powiadomień*"
                      v-model.trim="$v.form.carrier_email_to_notification.$model"
                      :isValid="checkIfValid('carrier_email_to_notification')"
                      placeholder="Wpisz email do powiadomień"
                      invalidFeedback="To pole jest wymagane i musi zawierać minimum 3 znaki i maksimum 255 znaków"
                    />
                  </CCol>
                </CRow>
                <h4 class="py-3">Kierowca </h4>
                <CRow>
                  <CCol md="12">
                    <CSelect id="driver_id"
                             label="Wybierz kierowcę"
                             v-model.trim="$v.form.driver_id.$model"
                             :options="drivers"
                    >
                    </CSelect>
                  </CCol>
                </CRow>
                

                <h4 class="py-3">Rodzaj przewożonego towaru </h4>
              
                <template v-for="(option) in productDircionary">
                  <div class="form-group form-row" :key="option.name">
                    <CCol sm="12">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedProducts[]" :value="option.value" v-model="selectedProducts"
                             :id="option.value" :checked="selectedProducts.includes(option.value)"/> {{ option.label }}
                    </CCol>
                  </div>
                </template>


                <div>wybrano: {{ selectedProducts }}</div>

                <h4 class="py-3">Wymagane dokumenty </h4>
               

                <template v-for="(option) in documentDircionary">
                  <div class="form-group form-row" :key="option.name">
                    <CCol sm="12">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedDocuments[]" :value="option.value"
                             v-model="selectedDocuments" :id="option.value"
                             :checked="selectedDocuments.includes(option.value)"/> {{ option.label }}
                    </CCol>
                  </div>
                </template>
                <div>wybrano: {{ selectedDocuments }}</div>


                <h4 class="py-3">Wymagane pliki dla dostawcy </h4>
                <template v-for="(option) in fileDircionary">
                  <div class="form-group form-row" :key="option.name">
                    <CCol sm="12">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFiles[]" :value="option.value" v-model="selectedFiles"
                             :id="option.value" :checked="selectedFiles.includes(option.value)"/> {{ option.label }}
                    </CCol>
                  </div>
                </template>
                <div>wybrano: {{ selectedFiles }}</div>

                <CButton
                  color="primary"
                  @click="submit"
                >
                  Zapisz
                </CButton>
                <CButton
                  class="ml-1"
                  color="success"
                  @click="goBack"
                >
                  Cofnij
                </CButton>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" :class="{ 'active show': isActive('tab2') }" id="tab2">Historia zmian</div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" :class="{ 'active show': isActive('tab3') }" id="tab3">Pliki</div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" :class="{ 'active show': isActive('tab4') }" id="tab4">
                <CRow>
                  <CCol md="12">
                    <CTextarea
                      label="Uwagi do dostawy"
                      placeholder="Uwagi do dostawy"
                      rows="9"
                      v-model.trim="$v.form.deliver_comments.$model"
                    />
                  </CCol>
                </CRow>
                <CRow>
                  <CCol md="12">
                    Podpis odbiorcy delivery_signature
                  </CCol>
                </CRow>
                <CButton
                  color="primary"
                  @click="submit"
                >
                  Zapisz
                </CButton>
                <CButton
                  class="ml-1"
                  color="success"
                  @click="goBack"
                >
                  Cofnij
                </CButton>
              </div>
            </div>
          </CForm>
          <br/>
          <div>
            <CModal
              title="Wybierz przewoźnika"
              color="info"
              :show.sync="warningModal"
              size="xl"
              :closeOnBackdrop=true
              @closed="closedEvent"
              :centered="true"
              :onclose="closedEvent"
            >
              <data-table-select
                :fetch-url="datatTableUrl"
                :columns="['id', 'email', 'name', 'surname']"
                :headers="{'id': 'ID','email': 'Email','name': 'Imię','surname': 'Nazwisko'}"
                :routeName="routeName"
              ></data-table-select>
            </CModal>
          </div>
        </CCol>
      </CRow>
    </CCardBody>
  </CCard>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import Vue from 'vue';
import CKEditor from 'ckeditor4-vue';
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import {validationMixin} from "vuelidate"
import {required, minLength, email, sameAs, helpers} from "vuelidate/lib/validators"
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
import {pl} from 'vuejs-datepicker/dist/locale'
import DataTableSelect from "../../components/DataTableSelect";

export default {
  components: {
    DataTableSelect,
    Datepicker
  },
  data() {
    return {
      warningModal: false,
      datatTableUrl: '',
      routeName: 'carriers',
      modalClasses: ['modal', 'fade'],
      checkedNames: [],
      pl: pl,
      activeItem: 'home',
      form: {
        carrier_id: null,
        carrier_name: null,
        carrier_nip: null,
        carrier_regon: null,
        carrier_email: null,
        carrier_postal_code: null,
        carrier_street: null,
        carrier_city: null,
        carrier_email_to_notification: null,
        driver_id: null,
        comments: null,
        transport_content: null,
        deliver_comments: null,
        carrier_phone: null,
      },
      confirmationTypes: [],
      transportTypes: [],
      drivers: [],
      productDircionary: [],
      documentDircionary: [],
      fileDircionary: [],
      selectedProducts: [],
      selectedDocuments: [],
      selectedFiles: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    formString() {
      return JSON.stringify(this.form, null, 4)
    },
    isValid() {
      return !this.$v.form.$invalid
    },
    isDirty() {
      return this.$v.form.$anyDirty
    },
  },
  mixins: [validationMixin],
  validations: {
    form: {
      speed_number: {
        required,
        minLength: minLength(3),
        maxLength: 255
      },
      ...
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closedEvent(){
      alert();
    },
    isActive(menuItem) {
      return this.activeItem === menuItem
    },
    setActive(menuItem) {
      this.activeItem = menuItem
    },
    goBack() {
      this.$router.replace({path: '/tasks'})
    },
    checkIfValid(fieldName) {
      const field = this.$v.form[fieldName]
      if (!field.$dirty) {
        return null
      }
      return !(field.$invalid || field.$model === '')
    },
    store() {
      let self = this;

      axios.post(this.$apiAdress + '/api/tasks?token=' + localStorage.getItem("api_token"),
        {
          carrier_id: self.form.carrier_id,
          carrier_name: self.form.carrier_name,
          carrier_nip: self.form.carrier_nip,
          carrier_regon: self.form.carrier_regon,
          carrier_email: self.form.carrier_email,
          carrier_postal_code: self.form.carrier_postal_code,
          carrier_street: self.form.carrier_street,
          carrier_city: self.form.carrier_city,
          carrier_email_to_notification: self.form.carrier_email_to_notification,
          driver_id: self.form.driver_id,
          comments: self.form.comments,
          transport_content: self.form.transport_content,
          deliver_comments: self.form.deliver_comments,
          carrier_phone: self.form.carrier_phone,
          selected_products: self.selectedProducts,
          selected_documents: self.selectedDocuments,
          selected_files: self.selectedFiles,
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response.data.status == 'success') {
            Swal.fire(
              'Sukces',
              'Rekord dodany poprawnie!',
              'success'
            ).then(function () {
              // self.$router.push('/tasks');
            });
          } else {
            Swal.fire(
              'Błąd',
              response,
              'error'
            )
          }
        }).catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response.data.message != '') {
          let errorDetails = ""
          for (let key in error.response.data.errors) {
            errorDetails += `${error.response.data.errors[key]}<br/>`
          }
          Swal.fire(
            'Błąd',
            errorDetails,
            'error'
          )
          window.scrollTo({top: 0});
        } else {
          Swal.fire(
            'Błąd',
            error,
            'error'
          )
          self.$router.push({path: 'login'});
        }
      });
    },

    submit() {
      let self = this;

      Swal.fire({
        title: "Czy zapisać dane",
        text: "zlecenia w bazie?",
        type: "question",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Tak, zapisz",
        cancelButtonText: "Anuluj",
        reverseButtons: true
      }).then(function (result) {
        if (result.value) {
          self.runSubmit();
        }
      });
    },

    runSubmit() {
      let self = this;
      self.validate();
      if (!this.$v.form.$invalid) {
        this.store();
      }
    },

    validate() {
      this.$v.$touch()
    },

    reset() {
      this.form = this.getEmptyForm()
      this.submitted = false
      this.$v.$reset()
    },

    getEmptyForm() {
      return {
        speed_number: null,
        order_number: null,
        data_start: null,
        data_finish: null,
        address_from: null,
        address_to: null,
        is_neutral_option: null,
        transport_type: null,
        carrier_id: null,
        carrier_name: null,
        carrier_nip: null,
        carrier_regon: null,
        carrier_email: null,
        carrier_postal_code: null,
        carrier_street: null,
        carrier_city: null,
        carrier_email_to_notification: null,
        driver_id: null,
        comments: null,
        transport_content: null,
        deliver_comments: null,
        carrier_phone: null,
        selected_products: null,
        selectedProducts: [],
        selectedDocuments: [],
        selectedFiles: [],
      }
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.datatTableUrl = Vue.prototype.$apiAdress + '/api/tasks/carriers-table?token=' + localStorage.getItem("api_token");
    let self = this;
    self.setActive('tab1');
    axios.get(this.$apiAdress + '/api/tasks/create?token=' + localStorage.getItem("api_token"))
      .then(function (response) {
        self.confirmationTypes = response.data.confirmationTypes;
        self.drivers = response.data.drivers;
        self.transportTypes = response.data.transportTypes;
        self.productDircionary = response.data.productDircionary;
        self.documentDircionary = response.data.documentDircionary;
        self.fileDircionary = response.data.fileDircionary;
      }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      self.$router.push({path: '/login'});
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

and Datatable:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input
            v-model="search"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Szukaj..."
            type="text"
            @keyup.enter="handleSearch"
          >
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @click.prevent="handleSearch">
              <font-awesome-icon icon="fas fa-search"/>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-2">
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="pageOption" class="mt-2 mr-2">Na stronie</label>
          <select class="form-control" v-model="perPage" @change="handlePerPage" id="pageOption">
            <option v-for="page in pageOptions" :key="page" :value="page">{{ page }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="table-head">#</th>
       
        <th v-for="(label, column) in headers" :key="column" @click="sortByColumn(column)" class="table-head">
          {{ label | columnHead }}
          <span v-if="column === sortedColumn">
                            <font-awesome-icon v-if="order === 'asc'"  icon="fas fa-angle-up" />
                            <font-awesome-icon v-else icon="fas fa-angle-down" />
            </span>
        </th>
        <th class="table-head">Opcje</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr class="" v-if="tableData.length === 0">
        <td class="lead text-center" :colspan="columns.length + 1">Brak danych do wyświetlenia.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="(data, key1) in tableData" :key="data.id" class="m-datatable__row" v-else>
        <td>{{ serialNumber(key1) }}</td>
        <td v-for="(value, key) in data" style="cursor: pointer">{{ value }}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" @click="prepareAddToTask(data.id)">Wybierz</button></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <nav v-if="pagination && tableData.length > 0">
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item" :class="{'disabled' : currentPage === 1}">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" @click.prevent="changePage(currentPage - 1)">Poprzednia</a>
        </li>
        <li v-for="page in pagesNumber" class="page-item"
            :class="{'active': page == pagination.meta.current_page}">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click.prevent="changePage(page)" class="page-link">{{ page }}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item" :class="{'disabled': currentPage === pagination.meta.last_page }">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" @click.prevent="changePage(currentPage + 1)">Następna</a>
        </li>
        <span style="margin-top: 8px;"> &nbsp; <i>Wyświetlam {{ pagination.data.length }} z {{ pagination.meta.total }} wyników.</i></span>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</template>

<script type="text/ecmascript-6">
import axios from 'axios';
import Vue from 'vue';
import 'vuejs-datatable/dist/themes/bootstrap-4.esm';
import {
  VuejsDatatableFactory,
  IDataFnParams,
  IDisplayHandlerParam,
  ITableContentParam,
  TColumnsDefinition,
  VueDatatable
} from 'vuejs-datatable';

Vue.use(VuejsDatatableFactory, VueDatatable);
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

export default {
  props: {
    fetchUrl: {type: String, required: true},
    columns: {type: Array, required: true},
    headers: {type: Object, required: true},
    routeName: {type: String, required: true},
    showUrl: {type: String, required: false},
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tableData: [],
      url: '',
      pagination: {
        meta: {to: 1, from: 1}
      },
      offset: 4,
      currentPage: 1,
      perPage: 100,
      sortedColumn: this.columns[0],
      order: 'asc',
      search: '',
      pageOptions: [100, 200, 500, 1000],
      selectedContent: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {
    fetchUrl: {
      handler: function (fetchUrl) {
        this.url = fetchUrl
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.fetchUrl);
    return this.fetchData()
  },
  computed: {
    /**
     * Get the pages number array for displaying in the pagination.
     * */
    pagesNumber() {
      if (!this.pagination.meta.to) {
        return []
      }
      let from = this.pagination.meta.current_page - this.offset
      if (from < 1) {
        from = 1
      }
      let to = from + (this.offset * 2)
      if (to >= this.pagination.meta.last_page) {
        to = this.pagination.meta.last_page
      }
      let pagesArray = []
      for (let page = from; page <= to; page++) {
        pagesArray.push(page)
      }
      return pagesArray
    },
    /**
     * Get the total data displayed in the current page.
     * */
    totalData() {
      return (this.pagination.meta.to - this.pagination.meta.from) + 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      let dataFetchUrl = `${this.url}&page=${this.currentPage}&column=${this.sortedColumn}&order=${this.order}&per_page=${this.perPage}&search=${this.search}`
      axios.get(dataFetchUrl)
        .then(({data}) => {
          this.pagination = data
          this.tableData = data.data
        }).catch(error => this.tableData = [])
    },
    /**
     * Get the serial number.
     * @param key
     * */
    serialNumber(key) {
      return (this.currentPage - 1) * this.perPage + 1 + key
    },
    /**
     * Change the page.
     * @param pageNumber
     */
    changePage(pageNumber) {
      this.currentPage = pageNumber
      this.fetchData()
    },
    /**
     * Sort the data by column.
     * */
    sortByColumn(column) {
      if (column === this.sortedColumn) {
        this.order = (this.order === 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc'
      } else {
        this.sortedColumn = column
        this.order = 'asc'
      }
      this.fetchData()
    },
    handleSearch() {
      this.fetchData()
    },
    handlePerPage($event) {
      this.perPage = $event.target.value;
      this.fetchData()
    },

    recordLink(id) {
      return this.routeName + `/${id.toString()}`
    },
    showRecord(id) {
      const recordLink = this.recordLink(id);
      this.$router.push({path: recordLink});
    },
    getDataRecord(id) {
      let self = this;
      axios.get(this.$apiAdress + '/api/carriers/' + id + '/edit?token=' + localStorage.getItem("api_token"))
        .then(function (response) {
          self.selectedContent = response.data.record;
          console.log(self.selectedContent); // here is my result @@

        }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        self.$router.push({path: '/login'});
      });
    },
    prepareAddToTask(id){
      const copyId = id;
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Czy na pewno',
        text: "Chcesz dodać tego przewoźnika?",
        type: 'question',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#d33',
        cancelButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        confirmButtonText: 'Tak!',
        cancelButtonText: 'Anuluj',
        buttonsStyling: true
      }).then((isConfirm) => {
        // now 'this' depends on the lexical enviroment.
        if(isConfirm.value === true) {
          this.getDataRecord(copyId);
        }
      });
    }
    ///
  },
  filters: {
    columnHead(value) {
      return value.split('_').join(' ').toUpperCase()
    }
  },
  name: 'DataTable'
}
</script>
```

I need show in console log in Main.VUE content which I get from modal / Datatable.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new to Vue.js I recommend you reading about `props-down and events-up pattern` which describes flow of data between Vue components.

1. Props-down part is describing data flow PARENT -> CHILD, meaning child components should receive data from parent components via [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).
2. Events-up part is describing data flow CHILD -> PARENT, meaning child components should send data to parent components by [emitting events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

To get back to your concrete situation, you need to emit an event from `Datatable.vue` component which you will handle in `Main.vue`:

In your `Datatable.vue` you should add this:

```
 getDataRecord(id) {
      let self = this;
      axios.get(this.$apiAdress + '/api/carriers/' + id + '/edit?token=' + localStorage.getItem("api_token"))
        .then(function (response) {
          self.selectedContent = response.data.record;
          self.$emit('content-selected', self.selectedContent);  <-- add this line
        }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        self.$router.push({path: '/login'});
      });
  },
```

Now, in your `Main.vue` you need to handle the event like this:

```
<data-table-select
      :fetch-url="datatTableUrl"
      :columns="['id', 'email', 'name', 'surname']"
      :headers="{'id': 'ID','email': 'Email','name': 'Imię','surname': 'Nazwisko'}"
      :routeName="routeName"
      @content-selected="handleContentSelected($event)"  <-- add this line
></data-table-select>
```

Now, add your function that will handle the event, in your methods add:

```
handleContentSelected(content) {
     console.log(content); <-- your data should be here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for yours answer. I have error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.$emit')

Comment: Sorry, please use self.$emit, I oversaw that you used `let self = this;`, rest is the same

Comment: At the moment there is no error, but nothing is displayed in the console :( I do not know if this code works :( It would be possible to close this modal window except display the result in Main.VUE?

Comment: Again, my bad I used wrong event name, I emitted `content-changed` event, but I was expecting `@content-selected` event, I edited my answer, try it now, it will work 100%

Comment: thank you. It's working  :) Is possible close modal after run event ? How can I make it?

Comment: I'm not completely sure how your modal works, but if I had to guess I would say, just add `this.warningModal = false;` in your handleContentSelected function